# Sagepay 3045 currency field missing?

Tags: asp.net, web, ip, opayo

I am getting the error in question and am aware it is misleading as in my case like may others it is to do with the crypt key.

I have a test and live site on one server that I am migrating onto a different server. The test one works fine, but on the testing the site to go live on the new server when getting to sagepay throws the error in question. Nothing has changed but the servers, this has lead me to believe that Live crypt keys are per ip based? Am I correct in thinking that stopping the old live site and making the new one live will fix the issue? If not does anyone else have anyother ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The encryption keys are not per IP but you need one for your LIVE account and one your your TEST account.

Comment: I have a same issue some one can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940754/status-detail-3045-the-currency-field-is-missing